# Shiny: Output will be shown in every menuItem

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a problem with my Shinydashboard: I created a map and i would like to show it only in a menuSubItem (TTTest1) of MenuItem "Test3".
As of now, the only content that will be shown is my map and the tabBox "Legend".
I assume that the sidebar I have, does not have a real functionality because even if i click on any item of the sidebar, there is no blank page - only my map and a tabBox and nothing really changes, as if it were "static".

Can anyone tell me what went wrong and where i did this (big) mistake?

````
library(shiny)    # for shiny apps
library(leaflet)  # renderLeaflet function
library(readr)
library(geojsonio)
library(shinydashboard)


sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Test1", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Test2",tabName = "charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
          menuSubItem("TTest1", tabName = "subitem1"),
          menuSubItem("TTest2", tabName = "subitem2"),
          menuSubItem("TTest3", tabName = "subitem3"),
          menuSubItem("TTest4", tabName = "subitem4")),
    menuItem("Test3", tabName = "choice", icon = icon("dashboard"),
             menuSubItem("TTTest1", tabName = "subitem1"),
             menuSubItem("TTTest2", tabName = "subitem2"),
             menuSubItem("TTTest3", tabName = "subitem3"),
             menuSubItem("TTTest4", tabName = "subitem4")),
    menuItem("Test4", tabName = "Prod", icon = icon("dashboard"),
           menuSubItem("TTTTest1", tabName = "subitem1"),
           menuSubItem("TTTTest2", tabName = "subitem2"),
           menuSubItem("TTTTest3", tabName = "subitem3"),
           menuSubItem("TTTTest4", tabName = "subitem4"))
             
    )
  )

  
  body <- dashboardBody(
    
    tabItems(
      # Map Output
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                leafletOutput("myMap"),
                
                tabBox(
                  title = "Legend",
                  id = "tabset1", height = "150px", width = "500px",
                  tabPanel("Explaining", "If this then that"),
                  tabPanel("Source", "Here you can find my data")
                ),
                
         )
      ),
    tabItem(tabName = "charts",
            fluidRow(
              tabBox(
                title = "Legend test2",
                # The id lets us use input$tabset1 on the server to find the current tab
                id = "tabset2", height = "500px", width = "500px",
                tabPanel("Example", "Hello"),
                tabPanel("Example2", "Hi again")
              ),
            ))
      
    )
  )

u <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "InfoHub"),
  sidebar,
  body
)

s <- function(input,output){
    
    output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
      myMap <- leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 1)) %>%
        addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap") %>%
        setView( lng = -87.567215
                 , lat = 41.822582
                 , zoom = 11 ) %>%
        setMaxBounds( lng1 = -87.94011
                      , lat1 = 41.64454
                      , lng2 = -87.52414
                      , lat2 = 42.02304 )
      
      
      bins <- c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)
      pal <- colorBin("BuGn", domain = completeCPM$OBS_VALUE, bins = bins)
      
      labels <- sprintf(
        "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g Points on a scale**strong text**",
        completeCPM$sovereignt, completeCPM$OBS_VALUE
      ) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)
      
      m %>% addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~pal(OBS_VALUE),
        weight = 2,
        opacity = 1,
        color = "white",
        dashArray = "3",
        fillOpacity = 0.7,
        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
          weight = 5,
          color = "#666",
          dashArray = "",
          fillOpacity = 0.7,
          bringToFront = TRUE),
        label = labels,
        labelOptions = labelOptions(
          style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
          textsize = "15px",
          direction = "auto")) %>%
        addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~OBS_VALUE,na.label = "Keine Datenquelle vorhanden", opacity = 0.7, title = NULL,
                  position = "bottomright")
    })
    
    
}
shinyApp(u,s)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using `tabName` correctly. First, you shouldn't reuse tab names in the `sidebar`.  Those will be clashing. A lot of your `menuSubItem` tabs are have repeated values. That should be fixed to something like...

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Test1", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Test2",tabName = "charts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
          menuSubItem("TTest1", tabName = "subitem1"),
          menuSubItem("TTest2", tabName = "subitem2"),
          menuSubItem("TTest3", tabName = "subitem3"),
          menuSubItem("TTest4", tabName = "subitem4")),
    menuItem("Test3", tabName = "choice", icon = icon("dashboard"),
             menuSubItem("TTTest1", tabName = "subitem4"),
             menuSubItem("TTTest2", tabName = "subitem5"),
             menuSubItem("TTTest3", tabName = "subitem6"),
             menuSubItem("TTTest4", tabName = "subitem7")),
    menuItem("Test4", tabName = "Prod", icon = icon("dashboard"),
           menuSubItem("TTTTest1", tabName = "subitem8"),
           menuSubItem("TTTTest2", tabName = "subitem9"),
           menuSubItem("TTTTest3", tabName = "subitem10"),
           menuSubItem("TTTTest4", tabName = "subitem11"))
             
    )
  )
```

Notice now there are no repeated `tabName`s.  These are what you want to use in the `dashBoardBody` to associate the sidebar with the `body` of the app.

If you want your `leaflet` map to appear in Test3/TTTest1, you need to use that `tabName` specifically. In the code chunk above, `tabName = "subitem4"`.

```
 body <- dashboardBody(
   
   tabItems(
     # Map Output
     tabItem(tabName = "subitem4",
             fluidRow(
               leafletOutput("myMap"),
               
               tabBox(
                 title = "Legend",
                 id = "tabset1", height = "150px", width = "500px",
                 tabPanel("Explaining", "If this then that"),
                 tabPanel("Source", "Here you can find my data")
               ),
               
        )
     ),
```

The connection between your `sidebar` menu and what appears on the `body` of those pages is the `tabName`.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation!
I just got into Shiny and this was a problem that I had no explanation for until now.
It finally runs like it should, thank you so much!